# WordPress wp_remote_get and Keen.io Event Creation

Tags: keen-io

I'm using WordPress and `wp_remote_get`.

I keep getting a 404 error trying to post to my event collection and I'm not sure if I'm even doing this right.

Here is the code I'm currently using:

```
$bucket = array( 'purchase' => json_encode( $options ) );

$keen_url = 'https://api.keen.io/3.0/projects/PROJECTNAME/events/installs?api_key=KEY';

$headers = array( 
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
);

$response = wp_safe_remote_get( $keen_url, array( 'headers' => $headers, 'body' => $bucket ) );
die( '<pre>' . print_r( $response, true ) );
```

Comment: some things to check: are you replacing PROJECTNAME with your Keen project ID? If this URL is not correct, that would produce a 404!

Comment: which guide are example are you going off of to compile this request? It is strange that you have an array called "purchase" but then you seem to posting to an event collection called "installs". what type of event are you trying to post?

Comment: This code appears to work, but no data is being stored in in installs

Comment: Yes, I obfuscated my project params.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to posting to Keen, and perhaps they are getting mixed here.

If you're [posting a single event](https://keen.io/docs/api/?shell#record-a-single-event) directly to the `installs` URL, I would expect your body to only be the install events themselves, and not contain a collection name like "purchase". What if you remove `purchase` from your `$bucket` and just have the JSON-encoded event properties?

Your final request URL would look something like this, where `data` is the URL-encoded AND base-64 encoded event body, e.g.:

`https://api.keen.io/3.0/projects/PROJECT_ID/events/installs?api_key=WRITE_KEY&data=ENCODED_DATA`

Perhaps you are using the method for [recording multiple events](https://keen.io/docs/api/?shell#record-multiple-events), which takes an array of collections and their events. If you want to try that method, keep the `purchases` part in your `$bucket`, and try modifying your `$keen_url` to:

`https://api.keen.io/3.0/projects/PROJECTNAME/events?api_key=KEY'` (notice the request goes directly to `events` and not `events/COLLECTION_NAME`

Here's an example of what that request looks like in cURL:

```
$ curl https://api.keen.io/3.0/projects/PROJECT_ID/events \
    -H 'Authorization: WRITE_KEY' \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    -d '{
      "signups": [
        { "name" : "bob" },
        { "name" : "mary" }
      ],
      "purchases": [
        { "price": 10 },
        { "price": 20 }
      ]
    }'
```